# column_spec function giving error in kable, kableExtra

Tags: r, latex, tex, kable, kableextra

I'm trying to create a re-usable block to create a table. Table will have just one brown and two columns. First column will have text and second column will have an image. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

create_table_with_image <- function(text, image_path, image_width = "3cm", image_height = "3cm") {
  # Create the data frame for the table
  df <- data.frame(Text = text, Image = "")
  
  # Define the column specifications
  col_spec <- list(
    column_spec(1, width = "50%"),
    column_spec(2, width = "50%", image = spec_image(image_path, width = image_width, height = image_height))
  )
  
  # Generate the table
  tbl <- kable(df, format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, col.names = NULL, align = "lr", escape = FALSE) %>%
    column_spec(col_spec)
  
  return(tbl)
}
```

This is how I am calling this function from another file"

```
# Create a table with image
table_with_image <- create_table_with_image("Example Text", "images/1.png", image_width = "5cm", image_height = "5cm")

# Include the table in your bookdown document
knitr::kable(table_with_image)
```

When trying to build, it gives the following error:
Error in column_spec(1, width = "50%") :
argument "column" is missing, with no default

What is wrong with the code?